# Why is jQuery adding backslash "\" characters to my string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping, jeditable

I'm using jQuery to replace the contents of an element with a string, which contains some  elements. The following is the code I'm using to create $value, the string:

```
var value =  '<span class="fn">' + $("#fn_").val() + '</span>';
$("input", this).val(value);
```

However, what actually gets outputted has backspace characters all through it, like this:

```
<span class="\&quot;fn\&quot;">Name</span>
```

I'm assuming this is probably a stupid mistake on my part, but not sure what I'm doing wrong? Appreciate any advice!

**EDIT**

For clarity, here's the full code, I'm creating a custom input type for jEditable that allows me to inline edit a vcard.

```
$.editable.addInputType('person', {
element : function(settings, original) {     
    var fn  = $('<input id="fn_"/>');
    var bday  = $('<input id="bday_" />');
    var wday  = $('<input id="wday_" />');
    var dday  = $('<input id="dday_" />');
    var spouse  = $('<input id="spouse_" />');

    $(this).append(fn);
    $(this).append(bday);
    $(this).append(wday);
    $(this).append(dday);
    $(this).append(spouse);

    /* Hidden input to store value which is submitted to server. */
    var hidden = $('<input type="hidden">');
    $(this).append(hidden);
    return(hidden);
},

content : function(string, settings, original) {
        var $data = $(string);

        var data = {};
        $data.each(function () {
            var $t = $(this);
            data[$t.attr('class')] = {
                                   class: $t.attr('class'),
                                   value: $t.text()};
        });

        alert(data.length);

        $("#fn_", this).val('Name');
        $("#bday_", this).val('Born');
        $("#wday_", this).val('Married');
        $("#dday_", this).val('Died');
        $("#spouse_", this).val('Spouse');
    },

    submit: function (settings, original) {
    var value =  "<span class=fn>" + $("#fn_").val() + '</span>' + '<span class=spouse>' + $("#spouse_").val() + '</span>' + '<span class=bday>' + $("#bday_").val() + '</span>' + '<span class=wday>' + $("#wday_").val() + '</span>' +'<span class=dday>' + $("#dday_").val() + '</span>';
        $("input", this).val(value);
    }

});
```

Comment: Can you show the code that outputs `value`?

Comment: How/where do you output your value?

Comment: I'm using jEditable, so it's part of one of its functions. Have edited the example above to show

Comment: This is not making sense to me - why are you stuffing a `<span>` into the **value** of some `<input>` element?

Comment: @chris you have class=fn right how come you are getting spouce , can you do a alert on value once , cchange the variable name from value to something else...

Comment: @pointy I'm making a custom input for jEditable, I've simplified it here but I'll be taking values from several inputs (name, birthday, spouse, etc), bundling them together in $value, and replacing the content of an hcard with them

Comment: @gov sorry, used code from two different examples and forgot to correct. Have fixed now, thanks!

Comment: What type of element has the ID `fn_`, and what data is contained within it? And the element you are setting the value of isn't a textarea, right?

Comment: #fn_ is an <input>, and I'm setting the value of another span with a class of "vcard"

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I seem to have got this working by using

```
'<span class=fn>'
```

instead of

```
'<span class="fn">'
```

i.e. removing the quotes from around the class name. For some reason the quotes are being put back in correctly in the output, however I'm not able to use multiple classes.

Comment: something else is wroing , while make html strings , we are supposed to give double quotes...

Comment: so the second example should be the one that works, rather than the first?

Comment: @yes we should always do like your second example only , the code may break ifyou give like first , for some reason it might be working here..

Comment: do one thing , provide your complete html

Comment: @gov I've edited my post to include the full script, does that make any more sense or should I post all the HTML as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set the HTML that is inside a span, one correct way to do it is:

```
.empty().append($('<span class="fn"/>').text($("#fn_").val()))
```

Or if you want to replace the element entirely:

```
.replaceWith($('<span class="fn"/>').text($("#fn_").val()))
```

Or if you just want to remove class `vcard`, add class `fn`, and set the contents:

```
.removeClass('vcard').addClass('fn').text($("#fn_").val())
```

This ensures that the value from the textbox is properly HTML-escaped before it is inserted into the `span` element. It's not correct to use `.val` to set the HTML contents of an element; use `.html` for that, although it is not necessary in this case.

Comment: i think he wants to make the input to show `<span class="fn">something</span>`, and not replacing it with the span.

Comment: Regarding your first code example, you can just do `$("<span>").class("fn").text($("#fn_").val())`, which is the preferred way

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that your submit function is executed before sending data to the server (take a look at Jeditable source), this means all your "spans" are sent to the server, so what is probably encoding your elements is your server-side script.

Cheers.